# Windows 10 GPU order

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, gpu

I have 2 GPUs (both gtx 780ti)
The problem is in the wrong order of them. For example, if I run Speccy program, it kinda inverts the index of those cards. The first card is shown as the second one, and the second one as the first one. It's not only in Speccy. For example, in Octane render (GPU render engine) the list of cards is also wrong. So I just want to invert the order of GPUs. How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: It's possible you could have the wrong perception of which one is card 1 and card 2? My first guess is that the primary card would be chosen by which PCIe slot it is in. Usually the PCIe slot that is closest to the CPU is the "first" slot. Check out your configuration and see if that's what it's doing.

Comment: 4 PCIe slots in motherboard, the first card is in the top slot (monitor is connected to this top card). The second card is in the 3rd slot (no monitors connected to it).

Answer (score -1):

Most programs have a section in the options to specify the card being used. If you are really willing to go in-depth into this to get it working, switching the card positions might work.